# Hive on hbase REfresh table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hbase, apache-spark-dataset

I have hive external table on hbase .I have seen in hive tables on parquet we need to do refresh table to get the latest data available. Do we need to same in hive on hbase as well ?

Answer (score 0):

verified the same and we dont need to call REFRESH TABLE for external hive table with underlying hbase table

**HBASE**

```
create 'ns_schema:table3', 'col_fam1'

put  'ns_schema:table3', 'row1', 'col_fam1:c11', 'first record'
```

**HIVE EXTERNAL TABLE**

```
create external table ns_schema.table3(
    key string, 
    col1 string
    ) 
    stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
    with serdeproperties (
      "hbase.columns.mapping" = "ns_schema:key,col_fam1:c11"
    ) tblproperties(
      "hbase.table.name" = "ns_schema:table3"
    );
```

**SPARK2 SHELL**

```
                import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
                import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

                val spark2=SparkSession.builder().master("local").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
                import sqlContext.implicits._
                spark2.sql("select * from ns_schema.table3").show(false)

+----+------------+
|key |col1        |
+----+------------+
|row1|first record|
+----+------------+
```

Now in HBASE Shell add one more row

```
put 'ns_gwm_idr_rz:table3', 'row2', 'col_fam1:c11', 'second record'
```

query the  SPARK2 shell

```
spark2.sql("select * from db_gwm_idr_rz.table3").show(false)

+----+-------------+
|key |col1         |
+----+-------------+
|row1|first record |
|row2|second record|
+----+-------------+
```